# Magento - Trying to save data on Edit in Adminhtml

Tags: magento

I am working with Magento 1.9.2.
I am working on a custom extension.

I have created a grid table fetching data from a custom mysql table. 
Here is my table structure:

[image]

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <expressdelivery>
            <class>VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_expressdelivery_resource</resourceModel>
        </expressdelivery>
        <vivasindustries_expressdelivery_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <expressdelivery>
            <table>VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery</table>
            </expressdelivery>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_expressdelivery_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <expressdelivery_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </expressdelivery_setup>
        <expressdelivery_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </expressdelivery_read>
        <expressdelivery_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </expressdelivery_write>
    </resources>    
    <helpers>
        <expressdelivery>
            <class>VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery_Helper</class>
        </expressdelivery>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <expressdelivery>
             <class>VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery_Block</class>
        </expressdelivery>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <expressdeliveryadmin>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </expressdeliveryadmin>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <expressdelivery>
                <file>expressdelivery.xml</file>
            </expressdelivery>
        </updates>
    </layout>   
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Here is my: VivasIndustries/ExpressDelivery/Block/Adminhtml/Delivery/Rules/Edit/Form.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery_Block_Adminhtml_Delivery_Rules_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
    {


        protected function _prepareForm()
            {
            $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                                    'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                                    'method' => 'post',
                                 ));

                $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('edit_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('expressdelivery')->__('SMS Information')));

                $Data = Mage::registry('expressdelivery_data');


                $fieldset->addField('FromItems', 'text',
                    array(
                        'name'      => 'FromItems',
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('expressdelivery')->__('Order Status'),
                        'class'     => 'required-entry',
                        'value' => $Data->getFromItems(),
                        'required'  => true,
                    )
                );

                $fieldset->addField('Price', 'text', array(
                          'label'     => Mage::helper('expressdelivery')->__('SMS Text'),
                          'class'     => 'required-entry',
                          'required'  => true,
                          'value'   => $Data->getPrice(),
                          'name'      => 'Price',
                          'tabindex' => 1
                        ));






                if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getexpressdeliveryData() )
                    {
                        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getexpressdeliveryData());
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setexpressdeliveryData(null);
                    } elseif ( Mage::registry('expressdelivery_data') ) {
                        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('expressdelivery_data')->getData());
                    }
                // Add these two lines


                $form->setUseContainer(true);
                $this->setForm($form);

                ////

                return parent::_prepareForm();
            }
    }
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery_Adminhtml_DeliveryrulesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Express Delivery'))->_title($this->__('Express Delivery'));
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('expressdeliveryadmin');
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('expressdelivery/adminhtml_delivery_rules'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        $smsnotificationId     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $smsnotificationModel  = Mage::getModel('expressdelivery/expressdelivery')->load($smsnotificationId);

        if ($smsnotificationModel->getId() || $smsnotificationId == 0) {

            Mage::register('expressdelivery_data', $smsnotificationModel);

            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu('expressdeliveryadmin');

            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('expressdelivery/adminhtml_delivery_rules_edit'));

            $this->renderLayout();
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('expressdelivery')->__('SMS Rule does not exist'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }

    public function newAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    public function saveAction()
    {
        if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
            try {
                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                $smsnotificationModel = Mage::getModel('expressdelivery/expressdelivery')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

                $smsnotificationModel->setFromItems($postData['FromItems'])
                ->setPrice($postData['Price'])
                ->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('SMS Rule was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setexpressdeliveryData(false);

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setexpressdeliveryData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }

        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
            try {
                $smsnotificationModel = Mage::getModel('expressdelivery/expressdelivery');

                $smsnotificationModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->delete();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('SMS Rule was successfully deleted'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
    /**
     * Product grid for AJAX request.
     * Sort and filter result for example.
     */
    public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
               $this->getLayout()->createBlock('expressdelivery/adminhtml_expressdelivery_grid')->toHtml()
        );
    }
}
```

I have problem only with editing the information and creating a new rows. I have no problems displaying the information.

Where is my mistake, why i can not edit, why i can not create new rows ?

Please if you don't see a problem here let me know so i can provide more information if you need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think problem may be in your column names

magento is using setters and getters, co when you are using:

```
$smsnotificationModel->setFromItems($postData['FromItems'])
                ->setPrice($postData['Price'])
                ->save();
```

in your save action it is translatedo to:

```
$smsnotificationModel->setData('from_items', $postData['FromItems'])
                ->setData('price', $postData['Price'])
                ->save();
```

but your column is `FromItems`

I suggest to modify sql columns names to:

`from_items`, `to_items`, `prices` which is magento standard and refactor your code. I think it should help.

or you may refactor your code to:

```
$smsnotificationModel->setData('FromItems', $postData['FromItems'])
                ->setData('Price', $postData['Price'])
                ->save();
```

etc...